# Is there a way to make the animation only run when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, scroll

An animation effect appears when the element is visible by scrolling.

I wanted the animation to start every time I scroll down and to keep the animation finished when I scroll up.
I've been thinking about it, but... I don't know how. Please help.

[This is the implementation page.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/dna7Lgqr/34/)

```
window.onload = function () {
            const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-observer]')
            const images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-img]')
            const options = {
                rootMargin: '0px',
                threshold: 1.0
            }
            const addClass = (el) => {
                if (!el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
                    el.classList.add('is-visible')
                }
            }
            const removeClass = (el) => {
                if (el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
                    el.classList.remove('is-visible')
                }
        
            }




            const doThings = (entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        addClass(entry.target)
                    } else {
                        removeClass(entry.target)
                    }
                })
            }
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver(doThings, options)
            const observer2 = new IntersectionObserver(doThings, {
                ... options,
                threshold: 0.4
            })
            targets.forEach(target => {
                observer.observe(target)
            })
            images.forEach(target => {
                observer2.observe(target)
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Here we take an example for that.
You have to animate a text while scrolling. then do this

```js
window.onscroll = function () { myFunction() };
var header = document.getElementById("header");

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 50) {
    header.classList.add("animate");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("animate");
  }
}
```

```css
body{
height:1500px;
width:100vw;
}
.text{
color:RED;
background:black;
font-size:30px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:1px;
position:fixed;
top:0%;
}

.text.animate{
animation:example 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes example{
 0%{
 letter-spacing:1px;
 }
 50%{
 letter-spacing:5px;
 }
 100%{
 letter-spacing:1px;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="text" id="header">TEXT ANIMATION</div>
</body>
```